# Is it good to operate the CPU at 71 degree Celcius

Tags: ati, cpu, overheating, temperature

My laptop configuration are Dell 3521 Core i3 3227U @ 1.9Ghz 4GB RAM Intel HD4000 graphic + radeon HD7670m 1GB DDR3 dedicated graphics.

As the CPU fan runs at max from staring of ubuntu, I am using `i8kutils` for fan controlling, by following the steps found [here](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in.html)

when Iam running the Android studio with the emulator, the GUI from the `i8kmon` shows temperature between 70 to 76 degrees of celcius, is it good to operate my cpu at this temperature or do I need to use a external laptop cooler like the things provided by the coolmaster

Comment: Usually a CPU should operate well up to temperatures around 90°C, I think. Maybe cleaning the dust out of it could already improve your value by a few degrees, but I would not do further steps yet, at least as long as it stays below 80°C.

Comment: TJUNCTION: Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die, is 105 C

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely it is not a good sign. Try to reduce it.** On running virtual machines in any laptops (using i3) will probably overheat your laptop and also makes your fan's speed to increase to improve the cooling rate.

**To solve this issue the driver which you installed is not the solution. Because it may cause your fan to undesired effects. Your problem may be due to the RAM capacity.**

### Before RAM upgrade

I used my lenovo laptop using i3 3110M ivy-bridge processor with 2GB RAM, 1GB dedicated NVidia graphics processor for running High-end games and virtual machines which made overheating of 70 to 78 degrees of Celsius with high-speed sounds from fan.

I came to know this will seriously reduce the life of the laptop. After searching many forums and websites i found that increasing the RAM capacity will not only boost the performance and speed of the system but it will also increase the life of CPU due to overheating.

### After RAM upgrade

After upgrading the RAM capacity of my laptop from 2GB to 6GB system became smoother and the temperature reduced to 54 degree celcius which is normal.

Normal CPU temperature details can be found here. Your laptop is probably ivybridge. See its range.
http://www.buildcomputers.net/cpu-temperature.html

**I advice upgrade your RAM from 4 GB to 6 GB or 8 GB for usage of VM(Emulators also) and High graphical purposes.**

Answer (score 0):

You could install thermald if you are concerned about the CPU overheating. Thermald will monitor thermal zones and will turn on various passive and active cooling mechanisms if it detects an overheating system.  To install, use:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

Comment: is it better than my current using `i8kutil` package,  and does it have a GUI like i8kmon to check whether the temperature is in control